# How to access a table row in CARTO.js histogram dataview

Tags: javascript, carto, carto.js

How do I access a certain row in a CARTO source?

For instance, I have Chart.js reading the `ticketcount` column using this:

```
var source = new carto.source.SQL('select * from ticketspercounty_copy');
var histogram = new carto.dataview.Histogram(source, 'ticketcount',{bins: 46});
histogram.on('dataChanged', (data) => {
       //console.log(data)

         let chart = new Chart(histo, {
           type: "bar",
           data: {
             labels: ['Abbeville',
                      'Charleston',
                      'York',
                    ],
             datasets: [
               {
                 data: data.bins.map(element => element.freq)
               }
             ]
           }
         });
       });
      // Add the histogram to the client
      client.addDataview(histogram);
```

but this generates an object that does not resemble the data like so:

[image]

I've pointed it to the `freq` field for testing but ultimately, I would like it to just read the singular value in each of the 46 rows.

Here is a snapshot of the table:

[image]

All I want to do is create a histogram of the `ticketcount` per `ticketcounty` and that information is not in the `bin` array.

Answer (score 1):

You can get any bin from your `data` object. As stated [in CARTO Developers](https://carto.com/developers/carto-js/examples/#example-histogram-widget), `bins` is an array, so you can use any js Array method in your code. I also recommend refactoring your code, I would create the chart outside the event and only populate the histogram once the data changes:

```
  const histogramDataview = new carto.dataview.Histogram(source, 'pop2005', {bins: 10});

  const histogramElement = document.getElementById('chart');   const histoChart = new Chart(histogramElement, {
    type: "bar",
    data: {
      datasets: [{
        label: 'Frequency',
        data: [],
        backgroundColor: [
          '#fcde9c','#faa476','#f0746e','#e34f6f','#dc3977','#b9257a','#7c1d6f'
        ]
        }]
      }
    });

  client.addDataview(histogramDataview);

  histogramDataview.on('dataChanged', (data) => {
    histoChart.data.labels = data.bins.map(x => `${x.start} to ${x.end}`);
    histoChart.data.datasets.forEach((dataset) => {
        dataset.data = data.bins.map(x => x.freq);
    });
    histoChart.update();   });
```

[Here](https://bl.ocks.org/ramiroaznar/da1dbd1d4f16adbd3a1e855d1686a6cb) is the complete working example.

Bear in mind that CARTO.js histogram dataviews return bins, not columns. But I guess that's a typo, and based on your last sentence, you mean rows. If you want to get all feature value of the viewport, I recommend using [CARTO VL `viewportFeature`](https://carto.com/developers/carto-vl/reference/#cartoexpressionsviewportfeatures) or [the SQL API with `fetch`](https://carto.com/developers/carto-js/examples/#example-dropdown-menu-with-data-from-carto-dataset) or something like axios.

**Update:** based on the last update what you need is a category widget using `sum(ticketcount)` as the aggregated function. This can be done in Builder without coding. But [CARTO.js category dataview](https://carto.com/developers/carto-js/reference/#cartodataviewcategory) ([example](https://carto.com/developers/carto-js/examples/#example-category-widget)) or [CARTO VL viewportHistogram](https://carto.com/developers/carto-vl/reference/#cartoexpressionsviewporthistogram) ([example](https://carto.com/developers/carto-vl/examples/#example-category-chart)) with `weight` parameter in combination [with Airship category widget component](https://carto.com/developers/airship/reference/#/components/category-widget) could do the trick.

Comment: I guess I'm not using the right tools then. I have a table that has a name field and a count field and I just want to create a bar chart for each name and using the count field. I've added a picture of the table in the question.

Comment: Yes, you need to use category instead of histogram widget. Going to update the answer pointing to the right solution.